# How do WordPress permalinks work?

Tags: wordpress, permalink

How does a permalink work? When I connect to a page such as `www.example.com/?page_id=13` How does the browser know where to go? Does it have to do with .htaccess file? (however mine just contains two comments:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 4):

**Permalinks in WordPress**

> Permalinks are the permanent URLs to your individual weblog posts, as well as categories and other lists of weblog postings. A permalink is what another weblogger will use to link to your article (or section), or how you might send a link to your story in an e-mail message. The URL to each post should be permanent, and never change — hence permalink.

`www.example.com/?page_id=13` will refer to index.php with parameter `page_id=13`.
Depends on your configuration (in Settings → Permalinks panel (Options → Permalinks before WordPress 2.5)), you can select a nicer permalinks structure for your WordPress, for example `www.example.com/your_post_title` with `your_post_title` refer to your title of the post you composed.

Normally, WordPress will modify content of `.htaccess` automatically, so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to **index.php** with parameter page_id=13.

Just like what would happen if you go to www.example.com, that is also just calling index.php.

In this case you're just adding the parameter.

It might not be index.php, but it should just be whatever you have set as your default page.